# Reboot failure after upgrade from Ubuntu 8.04 LTS to 10.04 LTS

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, 8.04

I bought our computer from Freegeeks with Ubuntu 8.04 installed.
I upgraded from Ubuntu 8.04 to 10.04 on Thursday November 10. I have an ASUS P4P800SE with Intel P4@3GHZ.

Installation messages were:
- Error loading Nautilus config info
- Replaced customized /etc/login.defs
- Replaced customized /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf
- 189 packages removed
WARNING: Failed to read mirror file

When I rebooted:

```
the usual ASUS screen appeared,
then "Loading GRUB"
then "starting Up..."
then "starting Up..." again
then a blank screen (the monitor went dormant).
```

I rebooted, started GRUB and selected:
 kernel 2.6.32-35 generic
I got the same results.

I rebooted, started GRUB and selected:
 kernel 2.6.24-29 generic

Here's what was displayed:

```
udevd [875]: error getting socket:  Invalid argument
libudev:udev_monitor_new_from_netlink: error getting socket: Invalid argument

Segmentation fault
Gave up waiting for root device
 Common problems
- Boot args (cat/proc/cmdline)
- Check root delay
-     check root
- Missing modules

ALERT!
 /dev/disk/by_vvid/c59c6361 etc...  does not exist. Dropping to a shell.
```

Then Busybox v1.13.3 started with the following prompt:
  `(initramfs) _`

But my keyboard was locked.

---

It appears the hard drive cannot be found. Any suggestion on how to remedy this?
Thank you.

---

Thank you all for your responses. I was hoping for a more elegant solution than a clean install. I'd prefer not to re-install all the software I've installed over the past 18 months.

Comment: Why not try a clean install??

Comment: Like mikewhatever said a clean install is the best option, especially with such old versions of Ubuntu. If you have valuable data in your home folder and it's in a separate partition than it's just a matter of not formatting it during the install, but format the root and eventually other partitions you may have.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem: I switched monitor from VGA to DVI.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it appears you had created two accounts. They are now merged so you can edit your original question.

Comment: Switching from VGA to DVI cured the hard drive not being found?

Answer (score 0):

Better option is clean install rather than upgrading. If you save a lot of useful data in the "Home" directory like `/home/yourname/` folder, it is better for you to set up 2 partition in the beginning of the clean installation. The first partition mounted with `/` and the other mounted with `/home`.

At least when you do the clean install on the next time, just format the partition with mount point of `/`. All you data should be preserved by then.

Sometimes even when you are updating machine from 11.04 to 11.10, maybe some errors will pop up. If not when booting, those will appear during the session somehow or the appearance configuration on previous version will corrupted a little bit after the upgrade process completed.

My final words.... clean install is better then direct upgrade using the CD. I hope that I'm helping....